# force encoding to SQLGetData function in odbc

Tags: c++, encoding, odbc

Please do you know a way to force an encoding(example utf-8) to retrieve data using the SQLGetData function in ODBC?

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.odbc%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_fngetdata.htm

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not so specific, the following might help you:

1. Encoding is not performed by SQLGetData.
2. You have to know the source encoding scheme (for later data manipulation)
3. Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715441(v=vs.85).aspx